# I am getting error in console "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." react，js

Tags: reactjs

When I right click to view the source code of the webpage, I am getting error in console "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." reactjs, what is the reason for this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuKQm.png)

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error, it's just the text that react will show to your users if they don't have Javascript enabled.

Also, you are viewing the page source and not the console.

You can read more about that [here](https://www.upbeatcode.com/react/solved-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app/).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I want to download her source code and run it locally, I tried Solved as you said, but it runs as a white page, what else can I do